# make.exe interprets $< strangely in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a problem with make.exe. I'm using the following makefile:

```
MCU=cortex-m3
OBJCOPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD=arm-none-eabi-ld
SIZE=arm-none-eabi-size
CFLAGS=-mthumb -mcpu=$(MCU) -g -O0 -Wall $(INC)
ASFLAGS=-mthumb -mcpu=$(MCU) -g -Wall
LDFLAGS=-Tscript.ld
OBJ=main.o InitRCC.o InitFLASH.o InitGPIOA.o InitGPIOB.o InitGPIOC.o InitGPIOD.o InitGPIOE.o InitGPIOF.o InitGPIOG.o
TARGET=Blink
.PHONY: all clean

InitGPIOA.o: InitGPIOA.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOB.o:    InitGPIOB.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOB.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOC.o:    InitGPIOC.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOC.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOD.o:    InitGPIOD.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOD.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOE.o:    InitGPIOE.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOE.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOF.o:    InitGPIOF.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOF.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitGPIOG.o:    InitGPIOG.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitGPIOG.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

InitRCC.o:  InitRCC.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitRCC.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
        
InitFLASH.o: InitFLASH.c stm32g476xx.h stdint.h
        $(CC) -c InitFLASH.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

main.o: main.c stdint.h
        $(CC) -c main.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

all: $(OBJ)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET).elf
        $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin
```

When I run `make all`, I receive the following message:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c InitGPIOA.o -o InitGPIOA.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -g -O0 -Wall
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: input file 'InitGPIOA.o' is the same as output file
compilation terminated

** error 1 ** deleting InitGPIOA.o
```

What did I do wrong? Why does make.exe insert `InitGPIOA.o` as `$<` and as `$@`? `$<` is not a target. I expect make.exe to expand `$<` to `InitGPIOA.c`.

Comment: The error message are showing definitely did not come from GNU Make.  So, the `make.exe` you are using is unknown to us and you'll have to edit your question and provide more details about it.  Please investigate where it came from and edit your question and add information such as what operating system you're using, what the full name of the make program is and what version it is.  Try looking at the online documentation, or running `make.exe -v` or `make.exe --version` etc.  Note that not all versions of `make` support using `$<` in explicit rules like this.